# Create a form for editing a single field of an entity

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I need to find a way for users just to edit a specific node field. We have a quite large content type and in a review process we would like some fields of a node to be editable for the revisioning user and some not. To avoid that the revisioning user needs to scroll through a large node form it would be very handy if he/ she would find a link on node detail page close to the text of the field where he/ she is pointed to a form just showing the field.

I found "Editable Fields" and "Quickedit" module which work not so well in our project due to some JavaScript conflicts. Additionally they do not really meet our needs as our main aim is not to make nodes editable on detail page. We just want to show a reduced form to the user for one specific field.

Does anyone has a solution how to create such a form? I think of something like calling the path "custom-form/[NID]/[REVISION_ID]/[FIELD_NAME]" which is connected to a page callback which renders a form for field [FIELD_NAME] in node [NID] of the corresponding revision version and validating and saving the input respecting the field's widget settings.

Answer (score -2):

You can install the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

[image]

Comment: I know this module but it does not meet my needs. I need a form just for a specified field of a specified node because some users may edit single fields just under more specific circumstances - they do not get permission to edit just by role.